# Trait mixin with conflicting members: Why my code can be compiled successfully?

Tags: scala, oop

I'm sorry, this question may be a bit long because I want to describe the problem and my understanding as much as precisely.

Recently I'm learning Scala's trait system.

I did some experiments about conflicting members, see the following code:

```
trait TA {
  def play() = println("TA play")
}

trait TB {
  def play() = println("TB play")
}

trait TC {
  def play() = println("TC play")
}

class MyClass extends TA with TB with TC {
}
```

Of course, this code compile failed as expected:

```
Error:(13, 8) class MyClass inherits conflicting members:
  method play in trait TB of type ()Unit  and
  method play in trait TC of type ()Unit
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in class MyClass.)
class MyClass extends TA with TB with TC {
      ^
```

My understanding is that

The linearization of class `MyClass`  is `{MyClass, TC, TB, TA}`, but since there is no `override` on the `play` of `TB` and the `play` of `TC`, so it compiled failed.

One workaround is mark `override` on `TA`, `TB`, `TC`, as following:

```
trait IPlay {
  def play()
}

trait TA extends IPlay {
  override def play() = println("TA play")
}

trait TB extends IPlay {
  override def play() = println("TB play")
}

trait TC extends IPlay {
  override def play() = println("TC play")
}

class MyClass extends TA with TB with TC {
}
```

OK, this code can be compiled successfully as expected.

But what about this:

```
trait TA {
  def play() = println("TA play")
}

trait TB {
  def play() = println("TB play")
}

trait TC {
  def play() = println("TC play")
}

class MyClass extends TA with TB with TC {
  override def play(): Unit = {
    println("MyClass play")
    super.play()
    super[TC].play()
    super[TA].play()
    super[TB].play()
  }
}

(new MyClass).play()

// -- Output:
// MyClass play
//   TC play
//   TC play
//   TA play
//   TB play
```

What surprised me is that this code can also be compiled successfully.

The linearization of class `MyClass` still be `{MyClass, TC, TB, TA}` and there is no `override` on the `play` of `TB` and the `play` of `TC`, the only difference is that I added an `override` on `play` in `MyClass`.

Why it can be compiled successfully?

Note that Scala is not Java or C#, there is no default behavior of conflicting members.

In Java, if you don't mark a method as `@Override`, the default behavior is overriding.

In C#, if you don't mark a method as `override`, the default behavior is hiding.

In Scala, if you don't mark a method as `override`, there is no default behavior, they should be conflicting members, IMO.

Therefore, I think the above code compilation should be failed, but why it can be successful?

Or my understanding is wrong.

very thanks.

Comment: You explicitly override in the final class and handpicked which implementation to call. Surly it is legal. That's how mixin works.

Comment: @texasbruce But I just override in the final class, the `play` method in `TB`, `TB` and `TC` still conflict. In other words, after mixin, what's the semantic of the method `play` in `TA`, `TB` and `TC`?  They are `override` or `hide` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 4):

Too see where the potential conflicts come from, we need to adopt the "point of view" of `MyClass`.

Let's review your examples to see why you get these results (to simplify I'll use 2 traits instead of 3).

### First example: the usual conflict

```scala
trait TA { def play() = println("TA") }
trait TB { def play() = println("TB") }
class MyClass extends TA with TB {}
```

This fails because both traits define a `play` method with the same signature, but it's not clear which one to choose for `MyClass.play`. One could argue that "the compiler could choose TB.play because it's the last mixed-in trait", but since no *intent* of overriding something has been declared, Scala rejects it. It could work in principle, but **the Scala team chose to force you to express your intentions more clearly.**

How to do that?

### Clear intentions 1: override in trait

```scala
trait T { def play(): Unit }
trait TA extends T { override def play() = println("TA") }
trait TB extends T { override def play() = println("TB") }
class MyClass extends TA with TB {}
```

You 2nd example shows one way of expressing the intention of overriding. Since `TA.play` and `TB.play` are declared with `override`, it's clear that they *intend* to override the method `play(): Unit` that is in scope. That's why the compiler allows `TB.play` to "replace" `TA.play` in `MyClass`.

### Clear intentions 2: override in class

```scala
class MyClass extends TA with TB {
  override def play(): Unit = {
    super.play() // super[TB].play()
    super[TA].play()
  }
}
```

Overriding the method in the class is another way of solving the problem. Here we know exactly what `MyClass.play` is, since it's explicitly defined. From the point of view of `MyClass` there is no ambiguity.

The compiler is fine with `super[TA].play()` because it's clear which method is called: the one defined in `trait TA` by `def play() = println("TA")`. So `super[TA].play()` will execute `println("TA")`.

`super.play()` is a bit less explicit, but the rules of class composition are clear: `super` in this context refers to the last mixin, i.e. it's the same as `super[TB]`.

Comment: Thanks. But this still has no explanation about what's the semantic of the `play` in `TB` in the super class of MyClass.

Comment: What do you mean by `the superclass of MyClass`? `MyClass` has two mixins, TA and TB, plus the "default" superclass `java.lang.Object` on the jvm.

Comment: What I talked about is class linearization. `MyClass extends TA with TB` => `{MyClass, TB, TA}`

Comment: I've edited the last paragraph to clarify what `super[TA].play()` does. The method `play` in `TA` is not undefined (same for `play` in `TB`). It's overriden by `play` in `MyClass` but still exist independently.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined behavior in the subclass manually.
Why are you surprised? What is incorrect in this case?

I think the main confusing thing in the example is that “super.play()” is legal and relates to the last inherited member - TC. I think this is just a workaround when we just take the last.
I suppose they could resolve the first case (that doesn’t compile) by this workaround - just take last inherited implementation.

Comment: What surprised me is that why I no need mark `override` to `play ` in `TB` and `TC`? What's the semantic of the method `play` in `TB` and `TC` in class `MyClass`? They are `different methods` or `override` or `hide` or `undefined` or `conflicing`?

Comment: You said "I suppose they could resolve the first case (that doesn’t compile) by this workaround". I do not think so, because as I said in the question, there is no default behavior of conflicting members in Scala. If Scala has a default `override` behavior like Java does, then you are right.

Comment: Well, `TB` and `TC` don’t know about `TA` nor `MyClass`, therefore it would make no sense to use `override` here. Their `play` method is the only one from their point of view.

Comment: @ElectronWill If "Their play method is the only one from their point of view.", why the first case (in my question) compile failed?

Comment: The first case fails because there is a problem from the point of view of `MyClass` (but not from the pov of the traits).

Comment: @ElectronWill But what about the super class of `MyClass`? From the point of view of the super class of `MyClass`, is it successful or failed? There are conflicing members in it.

Comment: When you do `super.play()` in `MyClass` the compiler takes the last mixed-in trait, here `TC`, and calls its method. There is no ambiguity nor conflict in calling `TC.play`

Comment: @ElectronWill If there is no ambuiguity nor conflict in calling `TC.play` as you said, then I can argument that the first case is also no ambuiguity nor conflict, right? Because following your point, the super class of `MyClass` is successful and no ambuiguity, so the `MyClass` should be also successful and no ambuiguity, so the first case should be compiled successful. The key thing is what's the semantic of the `play` in `TB` and `TC` in the super class of `MyClass` (a stackable class)?

Comment: that's a choice of the Scala designers - see my answer

Comment: @chansey (1) "What surprised me is that why I no need mark override to play in TB and TC?" - you need to write 'override' key word in case if you have method with same signature as in supertype in current class. this needed for explicity, it actually does nothing.

Comment: @chansey (2) "What's the semantic of the method play in TB and TC in class MyClass? They are different methods or override or hide or undefined or conflicting?" you dont have TB.play in MyClass, you have just only 1 method implementation in MyClass and it will be called if you call play() on the object of MyClass class. Even if you call it through interface or type expression/check of the superclass. E.g. val a: TB = new MyClass(); a.play(); - the MyClass implementation will be called. What might confuse you is that you can still call original super.TB.play(), but it is what it is.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov So "the semantic of the method play in TB and TC" is `undefined`, right? Because there is no way to explain what's the role of those `play`.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Note that the `TB.play` exists indeed (because we can call original `super.TB.play()` in `MyClass`), but it seems no defined semantics.

Comment: I don't quite understand the `no defined semantics` part (my definition of semantics might not be very precise ) If you want to give a "name" to what happens to `TB.play`, you can say it's *overriden* in `MyClass` (in the third example) but that's it.

Comment: @ElectronWill Note that Scala does not support multiple-inheritance (It may look a bit like in form, but not in essence). If Scala support multiple-inheritance, then you are right. That means there is no inheritance relation among TA TB and TC, and `MyClass` override the three `play` methods at the same time! But Scala does not support multiple-inheritance. They are class linearization `MyClass extends TA with TB` => `{MyClass, TB, TA}`

Comment: In the last example there is *no* relation between TA, TB and TC, and `MyClass.play` *does* override all the `play` methods. This is unrelated to the fact that the jvm (and scala) do not support multiple class inheritance. Class linearization does not modify the hierarchy of TA, TB and TC, it's only a tool to generate the correct result for MyClass.

Comment: @ElectronWill "there is no relation between TA, TB and TC". Yes, they are no relation in global perspective, but when they mixin to `MyClass`, they have inheritance relation in `MyClass`'s local perspective, because class linearization.

Comment: Right, you can view it as a "local" ad-hoc inheritance I guess.

Comment: @ElectronWill It seems that there is two perspectives in Scala, "global" and "local". In global perspective, Scala want to mimic multiple-inheritance, `TA`, `TB` and `TC` have no inheritance relation, but have the conflicting names `play`, so compiler force `override` in MyClass. In local perspective, `TA`, `TB` and `TC` have inheritance relation by class linearization, in this case, the `play` methods have exactly default behavior implicit `override`, imo. So the semantics is very weird.